# How do I pass variables to gulp-processhtml?

Tags: javascript, gulp, processhtml

I'm migrating from grunt to gulp and looking to use [gulp-processhtml](https://github.com/Wildhoney/gulp-processhtml) (currently using grunt-processhtml). I pass in the parameters the same way I do in grunt, but the variables passed are not found.

The Gulp code:

```
var environment = 'dev';
var processHTMLOptions = {
    options: {
        process: true,
        data: {
            message: 'Processed HTML',
            env: `environment: "${environment}",`
        }
    }
};
gulp.task('html:dist', () => {
    return gulp.src('./src')
        .pipe(processHTML(processHTMLOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<!-- build:template
    <%= message %>
    <%= env %>
/build -->
```

The error I get:

```
((__t = ( message )) == null ? '' : __t);
          ^
ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue. Unlike grunt-processhtml, gulp-processhtml only expects the options data to be passed without any other elements ('options'). Here is an example of how to pass variable to gulp-processhtml:

```
var processHTMLOptions = {
    process: true,
    data: {
        message: 'Processed HTML',
        version: `code_version: "${pkg.version}",`,
        env: `environment: "${environment}",`
    }
};
```